# Python itertools product start from certain

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I have a very big product expected from a itertools.product.

```
for result in product(items, repeat=9):
    # stuff
```

It takes a lot of time, and I am searching for a way to start from a certain item because I won't be able to do it on one run.

I could do the following:

```
gen = product(items, repeat=9):
for temp in gen:
    if temp == DESIRED_VALUE:
        break
for result in gen:
    # stuff
```

But it will take a lot of time, almost the same as if I was just restarting the program. So, is there a way to "skip ahead" without wasting the time on iterating the whole thing?

Comment: with 62 possible characters and 9 characters there are `62**9` combination, or `13 537 086 546 263 552` combinations, don't get your hopes up about cracking it with brute force.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although I have serious concerns about brute-forcing a passsword in the first place, I can offer an answer.

You can use `islice` to skip a certain number of steps in iteration.  This means that you would need to keep track of how many attempts you have done so far to know where to resume later.

```
START_VALUE = 200
all_combos = itertools.product(letters,repeat=9)

#start at START_VALUE and stop at None (the end)
combos = itertools.islice(all_combos,START_VALUE,None)

for i,password in enumerate(combos,start=START_VALUE):
    ...
```

note that this will only work for values **below** `sys.maxsize`.

You can also calculate the index of a given password with the same formula to convert bases:

```
def check_value(password):
    pos = len(letters)
    value = 0
    for i,c in enumerate(reversed(password)):
        value+= (pos**i) * letters.index(c)
    return value


>>> check_value("aaaacbdaa")
29802532
```